# Filtering access to admin

Tags: php, sql

I have a side menu that I want to to have the Admin option ONLY display IF the username is an admin.  Simply if they are an admin, it's there, if they are not it shows another link to their profile.

Again, KISS (Keep It Super Simple)...please I am an noob.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to your database 'user' table column 'is_admin' and set it up for user

get the value and do sth like:

```
if(isadmin($user))
{
  echo "your admin bar";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you go and do a Query to see if there are any records with that username, and the admin field checked on. If there are, then that username is an admin. This won't work however if there are multiple users with the same username, so you might want to use a user ID instead.

```
function check_admin($username)
{
    // Look for a person with that username, and the admin field is set to ON
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE User_Name="'.$username.'" AND Admin=1';
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    // If there are any results, the person should be an admin (given usernames are unique)
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) !== 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you would just use it as a check

```
if(check_admin("bob") == true)
{
     // super secret admin stuff
}
```

Comment: Okay, simple if/else statement.  Let's expand on that for a moment.
Admin is a Y/N field in a user database setup.  I would need to determine if the $username is an admin from the admin field first before the if/else...right?

Answer (score 0):

When the user connects, you can store a boolean in a session variable that says if the user is an admin. Then you can retrieve it :

```
if($_SESSION['admin'])
    echo 'The admin link';
else
    echo 'The profile link';
```

See [the php manual](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) to know how to use session variables.